# jquery: loading an html element with $.ajax or $.get methods

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I would like to learn how to achive the following with the other two functions, or at least the ajax function.

```
$('#myDiv').load('index.php #content');
```

How would I load #content in the index.php file, into #myDiv on the current page with the $.ajax and $.get methods?

The url param doesn't seem to take a selector with any other ajax method then load.

*this doesn't work...*

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'index.php #content', 
  success: function(data) { 
     $('#myDiv').html(data); 
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `#content` from the URL and in the `success` function, try this:

```
$( '#myDiv' ).html( $( data ).filter( '#content' ).html() );
```

It would be nice if we could do it your way, but.... Maybe the jQuery team can implement this in the next release.